# Beyond experience points, how do SE ensure the quality of its community moderators?

Tags: support

The screen shoot below is from the suggested edit review queue. The name of the actual reviewers have been redacted to protect the guilty.

[image: screen shot]

IMHO, one of the reviewers shows really bad judgement by approving this one.  Not only is the proposed edit a vulgarism that never should be permitted on this site, but it is deliberaly inserted in a manner that vandalizes the  original text.

As it turns there was one more vote for rejection than for approval, so the suggested edit ended up being rejected.

But I think this example shows that the community moderation system is vulnerable and depends on the assumption that community moderators is of high quality and able to show good judgement.  If the majority of the community moderators is lacking in quality, serious breakage may occur.

The only "qualification" I know about for being a community moderator for suggested edits is to have earned 2000 experience points.

Are there other "checks and balances" in place to ensure high quality and good judgement being the norm for community moderators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*For those unfamiliar with the term, we use "community moderator" to refer to any user with the various level of moderation abilities (which change based on reputation, and "diamond moderator" to refer to the elected moderators who have special abilities.*

In general, there are some checks an balances in place.

In most instances, a community moderator can't do anything immediately.  This is demonstrated above.  A high rep user rejected the edit first, then a medium rep user accepted it, and then high rep user rejected it.

There are also [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)<sup>1</sup>.  If you fail too many of them, you won't be able to review for a while (it's called a review bad).

Similar controls are in place for other community moderator powers (close votes, etc).

For actions that slip outside the controls, there are two options.

1. You can flag a particular post with a custom reason and explain what happened.
2. You can raise an issue here on Meta.DA.

In this particular case, appropriate action has been taken.

<sup>1</sup> Waiting on confirmation that this went network wide.

Comment: Do we have review audits here? [Last time I checked](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2952/16495) we didn't, and I don't see [meta-tag:status-completed] on my request.

Comment: @Mołot I am not sure; I asked about this and didn't get an answer, either.

Comment: I never seen one here. Given the fact I have 5 "reviewer" and one "steward" badges (all in about last 12 months), I think we can assume I would see one if there was reviews here.